# How to change the CPU priority of a .NET program permanently in Windows?

Tags: .net, windows

Some time ago, I was looking for a possibility to change a program’s CPU priority in Windows permanently and found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793359/can-you-limit-the-cpu-usage-on-a-net-process-object) that involves setting certain registry keys (“PerfOptions”) and values (dword:“CpuPriorityClass”) for the program below the registry path `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options`.

This works as intended for standard binaries that are executed in Windows.
However, the mechanism does not work for .NET processes that are executed in the CLR.

Now my question is: is there a comparable way to permanently set the CPU priority for a .NET program in Windows that is installed as a black-box (without access to source code)?